# NICOP or National ID Card validity requirements for returning citizens

Tags: pakistani-citizens, identity-cards, pakistan

What are the validity requirements for the National Identity Card for Overseas Pakistanis (NICOP) or the National ID when returning to Pakistan?

Can you travel with a card that will expire one month after your expected date of travel?

Comment: NICOP: National Identity Card for Overseas Pakistanis

Comment: The validity if your ID doesn't matter as it won't be checked. I have traveled with an expired ID, unknowingly, without a problem.